# Function is not defined - Function is defined

Tags: javascript

The problem I am facing is that after I have tried to optimize my JS to help loading speeds. I have ran into an issue that a function that worked prior is now seen as undefined.

What i have tried is to load the script after the page has fully rendered. After all html/css is rendered ths javascript can be accessed and used. Now my main search button function `GetSearchResults()` is considered undefined.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
        <div class="card">
            <h5 class="card-header">Process Report</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">

                        <label class="card-text" style="display: inline-block;">Software Name (Add-/Remove Programs)</label>
                        <input type="text" id="softwareName" class="input-group-sm mb-3" />
                        <button type="button" onclick="GetSearchResults()">Search</button>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label class="card-text" style="display: inline-block;">Process Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="processName" class="input-group-sm mb-3" />

                    </div>
                    <div class="col" hidden="hidden">
                        <label class="card-text" style="display: inline-block;">Application Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="appName" class="input-group-sm mb-3" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md col-sm-4">
                        <table id="softwareNameTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        Software Names
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <table id="processNameTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        Process Names
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <button id="selectValues" disabled>Save</button>
            <div id="selectedModal" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close" id="closeModal">&times;</span>
                    <h2>Selected Values</h2>
                    <ul id="selectedValues"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var selectedRows = [];

        function toggleSelection(row) {
            if (selectedRows.includes(row)) {
                selectedRows.splice(selectedRows.indexOf(row), 1);
                row.classList.remove('selected');
            } else {
                selectedRows.push(row);
                row.classList.add('selected');
            }

            updateButtonState();
        }

        function updateButtonState() {
            var selectButton = document.getElementById('selectValues');
            selectButton.disabled = selectedRows.length !== 2;
        }

        function openModal() {
            var modal = document.getElementById('selectedModal');
            modal.style.display = 'block';

            var closeModal = document.getElementById('closeModal');
            closeModal.addEventListener('click', function () {
                modal.style.display = 'none';
            });
        }

        function populateTable(tableId, data) {
            var table = document.querySelector(tableId + " tbody");
            table.innerHTML = "";

            data.forEach(function (report) {
                var row = table.insertRow();
                var cell = row.insertCell(0);

                row.className = 'selectable';
                cell.textContent = report.name;
                row.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    toggleSelection(row);
                });
            });
        }

        function fetchTableData(url, data, tableId) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (response) {
                    populateTable(tableId, response);
                },
                failure: function (errMsg) {
                    alert(errMsg);
                }
            });
        }

        function getSoftwareData(softwareName) {
            var softwareData = { InstalledSoftwareName: softwareName };
            fetchTableData(
                getActionUrl('SoftwareNameResults', 'Report'),
                softwareData,
                "#softwareNameTable"
            );
        }

        function getProcessData(processName, appName) {
            var data = { ProcessName: processName, ApplicationName: appName };
            fetchTableData(
                getActionUrl('ProcessNameOrApplicationNameResults', 'Report'),
                data,
                "#processNameTable"
            );
        }

        function getActionUrl(actionName, controllerName) {
            return '/' + controllerName + '/' + actionName;
        }

        // Button click event
        document.getElementById('selectValues').addEventListener('click', function () {
            var selectedValues = selectedRows.flatMap(function (row) {
                return Array.from(row.cells).map(function (cell) {
                    return cell.textContent;
                });
            });

            var selectedValuesList = document.getElementById('selectedValues');
            selectedValuesList.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous values

            selectedValues.forEach(function (value) {
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.textContent = value;
                selectedValuesList.appendChild(li);
            });
            openModal();
        });

        function GetSearchResults() {
            var name = document.getElementById("softwareName").value;
            var procName = document.getElementById("processName").value;

            if (name !== "") {
                getSoftwareData(name);
            }
            if (procName !== "") {
                getProcessData(procName, name);
            }



        }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: I would get rid of the inline onclick and upgrade to using addEventListener instead.

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` doesn't stop the JS from loading - it only prevents the function from happening until **after** the event happens. This won't help you with page speed.

Comment: you shouldn't define functions inside `document ready` or `DOMContentLoaded`. If you do then the functions are scoped to the `ready` and it won't be available outside of it

Comment: To underline @imvain2's comment, [MDN recommends the same thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers). Put your JS in its own file, load it with `<script src="yourfile.js" async defer></script>` (so that it loaded and parser async in parallel with the page but doesn't _run" until the page is ready) and then add event listeners to any element that should have them.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue stems from the GetSearchResults() function being defined inside the DOMContentLoaded event listener. This confines it to a local scope, making it inaccessible to the button's onclick event in the global context, causing the "undefined" error.

A direct solution is to attach the function to the window object, making it globally accessible:

```
window.GetSearchResults = function() {
    var name = document.getElementById("softwareName").value;
    var procName = document.getElementById("processName").value;

    if (name !== "") {
        getSoftwareData(name);
    }
    if (procName !== "") {
        getProcessData(procName, name);
    }
}
```